# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

I asked this question back on Oct 12, 2012:

[Extract Facts from an Army Portrait](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/66/extract-facts-from-an-army-portrait)

[image]

I thought it was a good question. It had 14 upvotes and 4 answers having 5, 3, 2 and -2 votes.

Someone named user104 deleted the question on Dec 24, 2013.  I would have thought a person with a generic username like that wouldn't have had the power to delete questions. When I look now, there is no user on Genealogy & Family History Beta named "user104".

None-the-less, I voted to undelete the question and then I forgot about it, until today (5 years later), when I wanted to show someone who might be able to help me with it, and I realized the question was still deleted.

Could Jan, Harry and/or PolyGeo please take a look this and see if they feel this question should be undeleted?

Comment: I'm not sure why the question was deleted, however three of the four answers were low quality one-line answers. "user104" was (is) a former moderator whose account was deleted. I'll check with the other mods and if no objections will undelete the question - but probably delete a couple of the one-line answers.

Comment: @HarryVervet I too have no idea why the question was deleted. There's nothing wrong with it -- in fact,I'mpretty sure I upvoted it -- so I wonder which question I meant to delete! lkessler, my very belated apologies -- if you had brought the error to my attention back then, I would have corrected it.

Comment: Weird thing is, it shows that I deleted it Dec 24 '13 at 10:31 at exactly the same time as Robert Cartaino converted an answer to a comment... more than a year after any other activity on the question.

Comment: I wonder if there was a subtle bug that caused a question to be deleted if two people were working on it at once.

Comment: Thanks all and no worries.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer no official explanation for why this question was deleted, but that appears to have happened only a few months after we went into Public Beta, so I am guessing that it was a casualty of us all trying to decide what made suitable questions for G&FH SE.

I could perhaps understand there being a vote or two for the question to be closed as too broad if we were feeling really strict on that day, but nowadays I think we would be unlikely to close it and extremely unlikely to delete it.

I have now undeleted it.